# Jquery Ajax Calendar skipping every other month

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, calendar

I have been working on this project for an ajax calendar which seems to have been working perfectly until recently. I clearly did something to mess this up. What seems to be happening is my requests are passing the appropriate month "count" but its returning the same data every other request. (i used a substring to make the console readable). In the picture below you can see the month names in the mix of html and how they are repeating twice before SKIPPING a month altogether (exception being december -> January) my question is: how do I stop it from skipping every other month and properly go through the months?

[repeating months](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m05dF.png)

this makes me think it might not be my JS code but my php code (which quite honestly is a mess, i nested if-conditionals)

```
$('#nextmonth').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "calendarajax.php?month="+monthcount, 
        type: "POST", 
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            var div = $('#ajaxfunc', $(data));
            $('#ajaxfunc').html(data);
            monthcount = monthcount+1;
            monthcountp = -monthcount+2;
            console.log("calendarajaxback.php?month="+monthcountp);
            console.log("------------------------------------------");
            var data = data.toString();
            console.log(data.substring(0,100));
            console.log("------------------------------------------");
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
          //what to do in error
          console.log("couldn't complete request: calendarajaxback.php?month="+monthcountp);
       },
       timeout : 15000//timeout of the ajax call
    });
}),
$('#previousmonth').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "calendarajaxback.php?month="+monthcountp, 
        type: "POST", 
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            var div = $('#ajaxfunc', $(data));
            $('#ajaxfunc').html(data);
            monthcountp = monthcountp+1;
            monthcount = -monthcountp+2;
            console.log("calendarajaxback.php?month="+monthcountp);
            console.log("------------------------------------------");
            var data = data.toString();
            console.log(data.substring(0,100));
            console.log("------------------------------------------");
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
          //what to do in error
          console.log("couldn't complete request: calendarajaxback.php?month="+monthcountp);
       },
       timeout : 15000//timeout of the ajax call
    });
})
```

this is my two functions that handle the requests (there are the "previous month" and "next month" buttons).

this is part of my php code (previous month specifically) that is in another file waiting for the request. the session variable is either 0 or 1, and is set to 1 when passing december to january and vice versa (this determines whether i increase the calendar year by 1). Yes its not the best way to handle it. I suspect it has something to do with my "$numMonth = date("m", strtotime('+'.$monthcount.' month'));" but am not too sure. My $_GET request variable is negative due to my lack of understanding of the date(); function and always inputting things as a "+" as shown above. Any ideas?

this code below is for "next month" button

```
if(isset($_GET['month'])){
$monthcount = $_GET['month'];
$time = time();
$numDay = date('d', $time);
$numMonth = date("m", strtotime('+'.$monthcount.' month'));
$strMonth = date('F', $time);
$numYear = date('Y', $time);
$firstDay = mktime(0,0,0,$numMonth,1,$numYear);
$daysInMonth = date("t", mktime(0,0,0,$numMonth,1,$numYear));
$dayOfWeek = date('w', $firstDay);
$monthName = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $numMonth, 10));
if($numMonth == 1 || $_SESSION['yeartrack'] == 1){

        $_SESSION['yeartrack'] = 1;
        $monthcount = $_GET['month'];
        $time = time()+60*60*24*365.2425;
        $numMonth = date("m", strtotime('+'.$monthcount.' month'));
        $strMonth = date('F', $time);
        $numYear = date('Y', $time);
        $firstDay = mktime(0,0,0,$numMonth,1,$numYear);
        $daysInMonth = date("t", mktime(0,0,0,$numMonth,1,$numYear));
        $dayOfWeek = date('w', $firstDay);
        $monthName = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $numMonth, 10));
    }   
}else{
    $time = time();
    $numDay = date('d', $time);
    $numMonth = date('m', $time);
    $strMonth = date('F', $time);
    $numYear = date('Y', $time);
    $firstDay = mktime(0,0,0,$numMonth,1,$numYear);
    $daysInMonth = cal_days_in_month(0, $numMonth, $numYear);
    $dayOfWeek = date('w', $firstDay);
    $monthName = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $numMonth, 10));
}
```

this is the image of the project just to see what i'm doing.
[calendar overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQl0d.png)

Comment: Please narrow down your question and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this code is the smallest amount of code I can give with it making sense.